# Software center and Update center not working after failed "moonlight" installation

Tags: software-center, update-manager, moonlight

I was trying to install *Moonlight*, but following the commands didn't work.

Now I don't care about that any more, but my *Software Center* and *Update Center* kept on crashing.  I managed to get rid of them through the terminal, but reinstalling them is proving to be a problem I keep on running into.

Output from the terminal, which is as I think a piece of information left over from the attempt to install `moonlight`.

```
E: Type 'echo' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

How to I get rid of this and reinstall my *Software/Update Center*?

Answer (score 1):

**Delete the second line from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`**

`sudo sed -i.bak '2d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update`

**If you don't care about Moonlight -- Delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`**

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update`

**For GUI repository selection**

`sudo software-properties-gtk`

[image]

Select as per your need and run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks man.  getting rid of Moonlight  helped get rid of the hang-up.   Do you know of any other reliable  opensource versions of Silverlight?

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I don't. And I'd like to say that show your gratitude as vote or acceptance.